# SQL - WHERE clause with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.about,a.user,b.user,b.title,b.article,b.description  
FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id
WHERE MATCH(b.title,b.article) AGAINST ('$search')
");
```

I need to expand this query to include `something like " AND user='$user'"` but where both `'a' and 'b'` tables are checked.

I could do `"AND a.user='$user' AND b.user='$user'"` but I will be adding 18 more tables so this is looking a bit bloated.

Is there any way to make things more compact?

Comment: You're going to have to explain the "I will be adding 18 more tables" part.

Comment: ...seconded. What 18 tables? They don't have the same structure, do they? If they do your design could be improved.

Comment: You should only need to check the username on one table not both as the `INNER JOIN` using the `user_id` has already matched them up.

Comment: I would suggest creating a mock-up of your database on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data so we can better advise you

Comment: At the moment there are 2 tables I will be joining 16 more, they all have different structures

Comment: Provided that the joins remain constant, I would suggest you look at [creating a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which does all the 17 table joins and returns the required fields, and then do the filtering in your `mysql_query` against the view.

Comment: @AeroX - is is true that if a result is found from table 'b' and I only have included "AND a.user='$user'" that it will still filter correctly?

Comment: @user1209203 TBH, table `b` shouldn't have a `user` field, instead it should just have the `user_id` field (this is considered normalised). An `INNER JOIN` will only return data where there is a match in both tables. So joining Table A.user_id to Table b.user_id ensures they both have a matching user_id.

Comment: @AeroX - Ok I have done as you have suggested and that has worked.

Comment: @user1209203 That's ok, I've posted up my comments as an answer for acceptance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to check the username on one table not both as the `INNER JOIN` using the `user_id` has already matched them up.

To be honest table b shouldn't really have a user field, instead it should just have the `user_id` field (this is considered normalised).

An `INNER JOIN` will then only return data where there is a match in both tables. So joining Table `a.user_id` to Table `b.user_id` ensures they both have a matching `user_id`.