# SQL - MATCH showing every row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure what's wrong here but this query is showing every entry from "about" and "articles" for that user. I have used a random keyword for the search to try and ensure only one result is given but the same thing happens.

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id

WHERE 

(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('$search')
OR
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('$search')
)

AND a.user_id='$user_id'

");
```

SQL fiddle of the problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e963d/1

Comment: Duplicated or OP put another question over the same query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323497/sql-where-clause-with-join

Comment: no this is a completely different issue, but yes the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id

WHERE 

(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('+$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('+$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)

AND a.user_id='$user_id'

");
```

[This article](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/) can give you more information about using `MATCH` in different ways

Separate searching in about, and title-article-description

```
SELECT a.about,null title,null article ,null description

FROM about a 

WHERE 

(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('BNMV' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)

AND a.user_id='1'

UNION
select null, b.title,b.article,b.description
from articles b 

where 
(MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('BNMV' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
AND b.user_id='1'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting multiple results though

Comment: Can you show results of query? and value that you use as $search?

Comment: I used BNMV as the search, the results are very long so I can't post them here, I've added that keyword to only one article to be sure.

Comment: I edited my answer. Add plus simbol into `'+$search'` statement. Hope it will work

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have created an SQL fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05a93/3

Comment: I finally undertand your problem. Just add DISTINCT. `SELECT DISTINCT a.about....` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05a93/4

Comment: I believe it's because the "About" column is being added to every row from the Articles table, I need to stop this somehow.

Comment: Do you need to search by `about` column or not? Show how result must look like

Comment: Yes all the columns listed need to be searched, the results should be the same as if a table was queried by itself, ie the data from each table should not be mixed up like this.

Comment: So for results from the articles table I don't want every entry having the "about" data. If that column must exit then it should be empty for rows coming from articles.

Comment: Next time describe your question more carefully

Comment: That's worked yes, I had no idea were the issue was originally.